# I want to get specific product by id. I am using redux toolkit and next.js 13. I am not using any backend api

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, next.js13

Here is my propertyCard code

```
<Link href={{ pathname: `propertyDetails/${data.property_name}`, query: { id: data.id } }} className='w-full flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-md max-h-[450px] xl:max-h-[390px] cursor-pointer hover:scale-[1.07] ease-in duration-300'>
    <Image src={data.img_url} width={800} height={800} className='rounded-t-lg w-full h-[55%]' alt={data.property_name} />
    {/* <img src={data.img_url} alt="image" className='rounded-t-lg w-full h-[55%]' /> */}

    <div className='mt-3 px-3'>
      <h1 className='text-purple-500 text-xl font-semibold'>$ {data.amount}</h1>
      <h1 className='my-2 text-xl font-semibold'>{data.property_name}</h1>
      <h3 className='my-3 text-slate-400'>{data.address}</h3>
      <div className='my-5 grid gap-2 grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3'>
        <div className='flex items-center'>
          <BiBed size={19} color='#BC7AF9' className='mr-1' />
          <div className='text-sm text-slate-400'>{data.property_features[0]}</div>
        </div>
        <div className='flex items-center'>
          <BiBath size={19} color='#BC7AF9' className='mr-1' />
          <div className='text-sm text-slate-400'>{data.property_features[1]}</div>
        </div>
        <div className='flex items-center'>
          <BiShapeSquare size={19} color='#BC7AF9' className='mr-1' />
          <div className='text-sm text-slate-400'>{data.property_features[2]}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </Link>
```

I am passing id through link to the propertyDetails page and getting that id on details page as below

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { selectProperty } from '@/store/PropertySlice'


import { BiBed, BiBath, BiShapeSquare } from 'react-icons/bi'

const propertyDetails = () => {

  const router = useRouter()

  const id = router.query.id


  return (
    <div className='w-full max-w-[1536px] m-auto'>
      <div className='px-3 my-6 lg:flex justify-between sm:px-7 md:px-10'>
        <div className='w-full lg:w-[65%]'>
          <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
            <div>
              <h3 className='font-semibold text-[#0D263B] lg:text-lg'>Porperty Name Here</h3>
              <p className='text-slate-400 text-sm lg:text-base'>Property Address Here</p>
            </div>
            <div className='text-lg text-purple-500 font-semibold lg:text-xl'>$3000</div>
          </div>
          <div className='w-full rounded-lg mt-3' >
            <Image src="https://exej2saedb8.exactdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Screen-Shot-2022-02-04-at-2.28.40-PM.png?strip=all&lossy=1&ssl=1"
              width={800}
              height={800}
              alt="propimage"
              className='rounded-lg lg:h-[500px] lg:w-full' />
          </div>

          <div className='flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4 py-2 my-4 border-[1px] border-slate-400 rounded-lg sm:max-w-[65%] sm:gap-7 sm:py-4 xl:max-w-[50%] xl:gap-9'>
            <div className='flex items-center'>
              <BiBed size={19} color='#BC7AF9' className='mr-1' />
              <div className='text-sm text-slate-400'>3 Bedroom</div>
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center'>
              <BiBath size={19} color='#BC7AF9' className='mr-1' />
              <div className='text-sm text-slate-400'>2 Bathrooms</div>
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center'>
              <BiShapeSquare size={19} color='#BC7AF9' className='mr-1' />
              <div className='text-sm text-slate-400'>1,500 sqft</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className='mt-6'>
            <h3 className='font-semibold text-[#0D263B]'>About this property</h3>
            <p className='text-slate-500 mt-2 text-sm'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Possimus, nihil explicabo fugiat corporis officiis inventore nobis voluptas excepturi.
              Nisi aliquid sit, perferendis sapiente, dicta, corrupti maxime velit voluptatibus accusamus commodi aut consequatur placeat?
              Velit repellendus illo nesciunt reprehenderit. Provident, cum.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className='py-6 sm:max-w-[50%]'>
            <h3 className='font-semibold text-[#0D263B]'>Overview</h3>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center my-2'>
              <p className='text-sm text-slate-500'>Listed on</p>
              <p className='text-sm text-[#0D263B] font-semibold'>1 week</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center my-2'>
              <p className='text-sm text-slate-500'>Date available</p>
              <p className='text-sm text-[#0D263B] font-semibold'>Available now</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center my-2'>
              <p className='text-sm text-slate-500'>Type</p>
              <p className='text-sm text-[#0D263B] font-semibold'>House</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center my-2'>
              <p className='text-sm text-slate-500'>Year Built</p>
              <p className='text-sm text-[#0D263B] font-semibold'>2018</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center my-2'>
              <p className='text-sm text-slate-500'>City</p>
              <p className='text-sm text-[#0D263B] font-semibold'>New York</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center my-2'>
              <p className='text-sm text-slate-500'>Cooling</p>
              <p className='text-sm text-[#0D263B] font-semibold'>Air Conditioner</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center my-2'>
              <p className='text-sm text-slate-500'>Parking Area</p>
              <p className='text-sm text-[#0D263B] font-semibold'>Yes</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='bg-[#ecdffc] p-5 rounded-lg lg:w-[30%] lg:h-[90%] lg:mt-5'>
          <h3 className='font-semibold text-[#0D263B] text-center mt-3'>Contact Owner</h3>
          <form action="">
            <div className='flex flex-col my-3 gap-1'>
              <label htmlFor="fname" className='text-[#0D263B] text-sm'>Full Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fullname" placeholder='Your full name' className='p-1.5 rounded-md text-sm border-[1px] border-slate-400 focus:outline-none' />
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col my-3 gap-1'>
              <label htmlFor="email" className='text-[#0D263B] text-sm'>Email</label>
              <input type='email' id="email" name="email" placeholder='Your Email' className='p-1.5 rounded-md text-sm border-[1px] border-slate-400 focus:outline-none' />
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col my-3 gap-1'>
              <label htmlFor="phone" className='text-[#0D263B] text-sm'>Phone Number</label>
              <input type='number' id="phone" name="phone" placeholder='Phone Number' className='p-1.5 rounded-md text-sm border-[1px] border-slate-400 focus:outline-none' />
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col my-3 gap-1'>
              <label htmlFor="phone" className='text-[#0D263B] text-sm'>Message</label>
              <textarea type='text' id="phone" name="message" placeholder='Message' rows='5' className='p-1.5 rounded-md text-sm border-[1px] border-slate-400 focus:outline-none' />
            </div>

            <div className='flex justify-center mt-5 mb-7'>
              <button type="submit" className='text-#0D263B border-[1px] border-[#0D263B] tracking-wide py-1 px-16 rounded-md active:opacity-70'>Submit</button>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}
```

here i am able to receive id.
Need guidance with how to pass it to redux store and get specific productDetails by id and how to send the product which will i get back to propertyDetails page

Sharing propertySlice for reference

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import RealEstateData from "@/data/data";

const initialState = {
  properties: RealEstateData,
  //Filter options
  locationFilter: 'Location (All)',
  propertyTypeFilter: 'Property (All)',
  priceRangeFilter: 'Price Range (All)',
  selectedProperty: null
}


export const propertySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'properties',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLocationFilter: (state, action) => {
      state.locationFilter = action.payload
    },
    setPropertyTypeFilter: (state, action) => {
      state.propertyTypeFilter = action.payload
    },
    setPriceFilter: (state, action) => {
      state.priceRangeFilter = action.payload
    },
    // To update property listing according to filtered values
    updateFilteredProperties: (state) => {
      const filteredProperties = RealEstateData.filter((property) => {
        const filterbyLocation = state.locationFilter === 'Location (All)' || property.city === state.locationFilter
        const filterbyPropertyType = state.propertyTypeFilter === 'Property (All)' || property.property_type === state.propertyTypeFilter

        const price = property.amount
        const filterbyPriceRange = state.priceRangeFilter === 'Price Range (All)' ||
          (state.priceRangeFilter === '$1000 - $3000' && price >= 1000 && price <= 3000) ||
          (state.priceRangeFilter === '$3001 - $5000' && price >= 3001 && price <= 5000) ||
          (state.priceRangeFilter === 'Over $5000' && price > 5000)
        return filterbyLocation && filterbyPropertyType && filterbyPriceRange
      })
      state.properties = filteredProperties
      // console.log(state.properties)
    },
    setSelectedProperty: (state, action) => {
      state.selectedProperty = state.properties.find((property) => property.id === action.payload)
    }
  }

})
```

In above slice RealEstate data is list of properties.